# Googlechart not working in Safari only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, safari, google-visualization

I make a chart with Googlechart. But it doesn't work in Safari only.
I get the error:

> a.getTime is not a function. (in 'a.getTime()','a.getTime' is
>   undefined).

My date code:

```
var date = new Date();
```

This is my code for the rows:

```
data.addRows([
    <?php
        $now = date();
        echo '[new Date('.date("Y, m, d, H, i, s", strtotime("$now -1 month -7 Day")).'), 80,       8,      96,     ,   100,    ,   , , ,   38, , ,],';
        echo '[new Date('.date("Y, m, d, H, i, s", strtotime("$now -1 month -6 Day")).'), ,         12,     ,       ,   102,    ,       , , ,   ,   , ,],';
        echo '[new Date('.date("Y, m, d, H, i, s", strtotime("$now -1 month -5 Day")).'), 100,  ,       ,   ,   ,   ,       ,       , , 36  ,   , ,],';
        echo '[new Date('.date("Y, m, d, H, i, s", strtotime("$now -1 month -4 Day")).'), ,         ,       ,       ,   ,       ,       , , ,   36, , ,],';
        echo '[new Date('.date("Y, m, d, H, i, s", strtotime("$now -1 month -3 Day")).'), ,         18,     93,     ,   ,       ,       , , ,   ,   , ,],';
        echo '[new Date('.date("Y, m, d, H, i, s", strtotime("$now -1 month -2 Day")).'), 120,  ,       ,       ,   ,       ,       , , ,   ,   , ,],';
        echo '[new Date('.date("Y, m, d, H, i, s", strtotime("$now -1 month -1 Day")).'), 85,       14,     98,     ,   54,     ,   , , ,   ,   , ,],';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `test` ORDER BY date ASC";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            while ($arr = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $date = $arr['date'];
                echo '
                    [
                        new Date('.date("Y, m, d, H, i, s", strtotime("$date -1 month")).'),
                        '.$arr['test1'].',
                        '.$arr['test2'].',
                        '.$arr['test3'].', 
                        '.$arr['test4'].',  
                        '.$arr['test5'].',  
                        '.$arr['test7'].',      
                        '.$arr['test8'].', 
                        '.$arr['test9'].',  
                        '.$arr['test10'].', 
                        '.$arr['test11'].', 
                        '.$arr['test12'].', 
                        '.$arr['test13'].',
                    ],
                ';
            }
        }
    ?>
    ]
);
```

I think that here goes something wrong with the date.

I can't find why it not works in Safari only.

Comment: i don't have a way to test on safari but the date constructor used _should work_ -- only thing -- the leading zeroes the format produces, don't see why this would cause an issue but if you can rule it out?? --> `new Date(2017, 01, 07, 00, 00, 00)` -- vs. --> ``new Date(2017, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0)`` -- _it's a stretch_

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. I tried it but it still doesn't work in Safari only..

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe try loading the dates using json string format

`"Date(2017, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0)"`

this would probably require some hefty changes to the layout of your code,
but may be worth it if it will work

---

instead of using the `addRows` method, build the json string first,
then create the `DataTable`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var jsonData = '{"cols": [{"label": "Date", "type": "date"}, {"label": "Value", "type": "number"}], "rows": [{"c":[{"v": "Date(2017, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0)"}, {"v": 1}]}, {"c":[{"v": "Date(2017, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0)"}, {"v": 2}]}]}';

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'chart_div',
      dataTable: data
    });
    table.draw();
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```